# where is the singularity of this function?

Tags: functions, hyperbolic-functions

Consider the following function $\ f:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ given by:

$$f(x) = - \tanh\left(3 x - \tanh^{-1}( u_{0} )\right)$$

In the above, $u_{0}$ is a constant where $u_{0} \in (-\infty, -1) \cup (1, \infty)$.

When I plot this function, it is clear that there is one singularity. I'm trying to find out for which value of $x$ does this singularity occur.

I've been scratching my head about this for too long, so I thought I'd ask here.

Comment: This is weird because your $u_0$ is outside of the range of $\tanh: \Bbb{R} \rightarrow \Bbb{R}$

Comment: The answer appears to be at $Re(\tanh^{-1}(u_0))/3$. Not sure why.

Comment: Hint: Use the addition formula $\tanh(a-b) = \frac{\tanh(a)-\tanh(b)}{1-\tanh(a)\tanh(b)}$

Answer (score 2):

The singularities of $\tanh{z}=\displaystyle\frac{e^{2z}-1}{e^{2z}+1}$ occur when $e^{2z}+1=0$, then you need to solve

$$\displaystyle e^{2(3z-\tanh^{-1}{u_0})}+1=0,$$

when $z\in \Bbb{C}.$